# How to disable the shared folder icon on Windows XP?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, file-sharing

When I share a folder through file sharing, it automatically has a hand under it that tells you it is a shared folder. How can I disable that?

In this picture, the "Family Photos" folder has the hand I'm talking about:

[image: Windows explorer screenshot with a shared folder]

Comment: This is a funny question because with the newer versions of Windows this has been removed altogether. Now we see a lot of people asking how to get them back. So one solution would be to upgrade to Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open Registry Editor.
2. Go to the following Registry key:

   `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Icons`
3. If this key doesn't exist, create it. If it exists, backup the `Shell Icons` registry key by exporting it. To export it, right click the `Shell Icons` key, click Export and then save it somewhere as a file.
4. Create new string value (`REG_SZ`):

   - Name: `28`
   - Value: `%SystemRoot%\System32\shell32.dll,-50`
   - [image: Shell Icons key]
5. Rebuild icon cache:

   - Delete file `C:\Documents and Settings\USERNAME\Local Settings\Application Data\IconCache.db`
6. Restart the Explorer (kill it, logoff\logon or reboot)